# Result set order changing in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result set and need to be displayed as it is on the screen.But the problem is while displaying each row of the result set using echo command the order is getting changed.Can anyone say why this is happening and provide me a way to overcome it.Here are my actual and printed outputs.

Actual Result set:

```
JAIKE-ILENE-WACKI-MAZIE-REGLE-SBJ-KMMU  
LVZ-HARTY-MUGZY-STW 
MAZIE-SIXIE-SBJ-KMMU  
PXT-LOUIE-GATBY-RAZER-BUZIE-JAIKE-ILENE-WACKI-MAZIE  
SWANN-GATBY-RAZER-BUZIE-JAIKE-ILENE-WACKI-MAZIE
```

Output:

```
 JAIKE-SBJ-ILENE-KMMU-WACKI-MAZIE-REGLE
 MUGZY-STW-LVZ-HARTY
 SBJ-KMMU-MAZIE-SIXIE
 ILENE-GATBY-WACKI-RAZER-MAZIE-BUZIE-PXT-JAIKE-LOUIE
 WACKI-RAZER-MAZIE-BUZIE-JAIKE-SWANN-ILENE-GATBY
```

Here is my code

```
$sql3="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l.fix_ident SEPARATOR '-') AS fix_seq,l.airport_ident,x.star_ident,x.transition_ident,
                 x.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg l
                 JOIN
                    (SELECT DISTINCT c.airport_ident,c.star_ident,c.transition_ident,c.fix_ident
                     FROM corept.std_star_leg c
                     INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type
                           FROM corept.std_star_leg
                           WHERE data_supplier='J'
                           AND airport_ident='KMMU'
                           GROUP BY star_ident,
                           transition_ident)b ON c.sequence_num=b.seq
                           AND c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
                           LEFT JOIN
                               (SELECT name,trans
                                FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars
                                WHERE apt='KMMU'
                                AND name!=trans) d
                                ON d.name=c.star_ident
                                AND d.trans=c.fix_ident
                                WHERE c.data_supplier='J'
                                AND c.airport_ident='KMMU' AND d.name is null)x
                                where l.airport_ident='KMMU' and l.transition_ident=x.transition_ident
                                and l.star_ident=x.star_ident and l.data_supplier='J'
                                group by x.star_ident,x.transition_ident
                                order by l.star_ident,x.transition_ident,l.sequence_num";
  $res3=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3);  
if($res3)
  {
    while($newArray3=mysqli_fetch_array($res3,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    $apt=$newArray3['airport_ident'];
    $star_ident=$newArray3['star_ident'];
    $trans_ident=$newArray3['transition_ident'];
    $fix_ident=$newArray3['fix_ident'];
    $fix_seq=$newArray3['fix_seq'];
    echo $apt.",".$star_ident.",".$trans_ident.",".$fix_ident.",COREPT,".$fix_seq;
    echo "<br>";
    }
  }
 else
 {
   printf("ERROR:%s\n",mysqli_error($mysqli));
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking me show the entire script or else the query?

Comment: How do you know the order of the "actual result set" ?

Comment: the way how you printing output.

Comment: How do you get the data from the database?

Comment: @Adder I didnt gut u.I used connection statements but i omitted them here

Comment: Try moving the last "order by" from the joined table into the outermost select. (It is ok, you showed what I wanted to see)

Comment: No the query is working fine..the problem is with the php code.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432547/group-concat-change-group-by-order There is an ORDER BY clause for the GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you for your help.But when i run the query in mysql query browser i am getting the result correctly.But when displayed it using php i am going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks overly complex.  It *appears* to be finding the groupwise maximum `std_star_leg` records by `sequence_num` (grouped on `start_ident` and `transition_ident`), excluding those for which there is already a matching non-self-referencing `deploy_star`, then returning the results grouped again with all matching `fix_ident` values concatenated into a string?

If so, the following greatly simplified query ought to achieve the same outcome:

```sql
SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(fix_ident SEPARATOR '-') AS fix_seq,
         airport_ident,
         star_ident,
         transition_ident
FROM     corept.std_star_leg l NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   star_ident, transition_ident,
                    data_supplier, airport_ident,
                    MAX(sequence_num) sequence_num
           FROM     corept.std_star_leg
           WHERE    data_supplier = 'J'
                AND airport_ident = 'KMMU'
           GROUP BY star_ident, transition_ident
         ) b
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT NULL
           FROM   skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d
           WHERE  d.name != d.trans
              AND d.name  = l.star_ident
              AND d.trans = l.fix_ident
              AND d.apt   = l.airport_ident
         )
GROUP BY star_ident, transition_ident
```

Note that whereas you were previously selecting `x.fix_ident` in the outermost select list, I have omitted such column  because its value would be indeterminately selected by the server from amongst those in the `fix_seq`.

Now, as to your problem (which *appears* to be related to the order in which `fix_ident` values appear within the `GROUP_CONCAT()` string `fix_seq`—although it's terribly hard to appreciate that from your question), perhaps you want to use the `ORDER BY` parameter to the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function?  For example:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fix_ident SEPARATOR '-' ORDER BY ...) AS fix_seq
```

However, it is not clear to me what ordering you require (the only `ORDER BY` clause in your original query was entirely redundant).